# Search bar disappears during scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've read some Stack OverFlow posts and nothing from there has worked. I have one simple problem that shouldn't be incredibly difficult to solve. I have to stop the search bar from disappearing when scrolling on the tableview that it is attached to.

I have tried:

1. set the tableview to .plain to make the header view sticky, but that didn't work.
2. I tried navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false, but this may not have worked because searchController.searchBar is set equal to tableView.tableViewHeader.

Here is my viewDidLoad, which should contain the relevant code when this works, if it is indeed possible:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 246/255, blue: 243/255, alpha: 1)
    tableView.register(SearchTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchTVC")
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .darkGray//UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.convertHexColor(hex: "eaeaea")
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.text = ""
    addConstraints()
    presentInitialView()
}
```

Comment: Try setting `navigationItem.searchController = searchController` instead of `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`

Comment: Thanks, when I tried that it resulted in the search bar disappearing for some reason. It's definitely the logical thing to do. And this didn't change if I set the nav bar's isHidden property to false.

Comment: Try setting `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false`

Comment: That still results in the search bar never appearing.